# RoR active record restrict display expand update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I stuck with this, and the questions/answers are too deep, or not fitting my prob. I think my question is easy to solve with RoR and a standard problem with rails. I still have not found my rails 'I got it'

Imagine (abstract situation) I want to store passwords (no I do not in rl). I have a table passwords with a `(ID), name, password_clear, password_hash`.

So what do I want to do/have:

if someone touches `password_clear` in any view I want an error.
I have an addional `password` (field?) for updating; this one i got with

```
class Passdata < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name,:password
  def password
     '********' 
   end
   ...
```

but on update? If Password is changed I would like to update `password_clear, password_hash` and dissmiss `password`

so there I got stuck

please, where to find documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PREMISE** I don't like clog up ActiveRecord objects with this kind of code. However, this is *still* the "Rails Way"

I've also hypothesized that with "touch" you intend "access to" and that you want to update `password_clear` and `password_hash` only on `#save`.

```
class Passdata < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name

  def password
    '********' 
  end
  def password=(value)
    write_attribute(:password_clear, @password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end

  def password_hash=(value)
    # do some kind of hashing
  end

  # noone can access password_clear in a canonical way
  def password_clear
    raise Passdata::AccessDenied.new
  end
end

class Passdata::AccessDenied < StandardError; end
```

Optionally you could use `before_save` hook to update passwords.

However, you really **should not** store your user's clear password in database! That's more then bad code...

Comment: all hypotize - true. I dont store a password - it was just an example! The rest I will try to understand tomorrow